# Angular 8 toggle switch data binding

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular8, toggleswitch

I'm try to create toggle switch like this

[image]

and when i try to bind the data into switch using [checked] like this,

```
 <div class="mb-3">
      <div class="d-flex mb-2">
        <div class="p-2 w-100 bd-highlight">{{ 'BasicData.DeleteDoc' | translate }}</div>
        <div class="p-2 flex-shrink-1">
          <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
            <input name="deleteDoc" id="deleteDoc" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" [checked]="ConfigList[4].FieldValue" (change)="updateControlSettings(5)">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="deleteDoc"></label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and there are the data i received from service

```
[
    {
        "Id": 4,
        "FieldName": "Insert Doc",
        "FieldDescription": "Insert Doc",
        "FieldType": "boolean",
        "FieldValue": true
    },
    {
        "Id": 5,
        "FieldName": "DeleteDocument",
        "FieldDescription": "DeleteDocument",
        "FieldType": "boolean",
        "FieldValue": true
    }
]
```

then value is undefined. any suggestion to fix this one?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the checkbox to be **checked** in the above scenario, you can use **Safe Navigation Operator** - https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator.

Like below -

```
[checked]="ConfigList[4]?.FieldValue"
```

Comment: still get the same

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="custom-control custom-switch"  *ngIf="ConfigList">
            <input name="deleteDoc" id="deleteDoc" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" [checked]="ConfigList[4].FieldValue" (change)="updateControlSettings(ConfigList[4])">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="deleteDoc"></label>
```

This *ngIf="ConfigList" does the trick